# How to execute JS in HTML template Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have object JS was returned by AJAX. In this object there is field `map` that contents JS code.

When I do: `{{data.map.js}}` in template HTML, it gives me text instead working JS code.

This is code in template:

```
{{data.map.js}}
{{data.map.html}}
```

Object from response Ajax (short code):

```
   map { html: "<div id="map_canvas" style="width:566px; height:310px;"></div>"
    js: "↵          <script type="text/javascript">↵...}
```

Comment: Can you show a MWE or part of the code involved ? Have you tried to put the javascript into a <script> tag?

Comment: Yes, look question again

Comment: You haven't answered my second question :) Also your question excludes any html so we don't know where you are trying to execute the javascript.
the angular {{ }} tags are meant to evaluate to text, so this is working as intended. If you wish to execute javascript, I think you should add script tags at the end of your html document.

Comment: No, I dont try to put `<script>` I get JS with tag `<script>` already

Comment: @Hamed you're going to need a directive to handle this, either one that exists or will need to write your own so you can check to verify the external script has completed loading.  What specific map or JS code are you trying to integrate?

Comment: What @shaunhusain says is probably the best, maybe this will help: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/08/dynamically-injecting-script-tags-with-angularjs.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular documentation suggests you may be able to execute js code via **eval()**. I have not done this personally but take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax for angular in html:

```
{{$on.constructor('alert(1)')()}}
```

This should work in regular html for `ng-app` attribute